# Backbone.js using el doesn't work but using $('selector') does. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, backbone.js

So, I admit that it might be tricky for somebody to follow my design and build patterns. But I will try best to describe the issue, although I feel this might be easier than getting you to understand my project :) But hell I've spent 3 days trying to figure this one out.

**Summery of technical layout**

- I have a global view (lets call this `GV`, for global view), everything goes through this template.
- I have navigation, this can call one of the 5 separate views on click.
- Each of these views first uses the same view (`DV` for defaultView) which then extends this view and loads details from its own `JST` (OV for OwnView)
- The problem is that, when clicking to load an OV the `element` that it is bound to load into (`target`) has not yet been rendered to the page. It is however available in the `DOM`, and in fact updates the `DV` with its `OV` but does not render to the page.

**Brief overview - To give you a idea of how my views are set up and what extends what**

1. GV - Loads: login, Home, Global Navigation
2. DV - Loads: the navigation for this section.

   - DV extends GV: `SD.defaultView.extend`
3. OV - Loads: h2, icon for the option and buttons

   - each OV extends DV so that I can keep all the click events in one view and not have to paste code all over: `SD.defaultSexView.extend`

**The problem**

`OV` loads into an element that is inside `DV`. `GV` and `DV` all load perfectly. I can click from, `login -> home -> navigation -> through` which would then load in the `DV`. This is where the interactions break down. All that is loaded is whatever was inside the `JST` for `DV`

**Build**

Just to give some background information:

- I am using `JST`'s to precompile all of my templates.
- `main.js` loads all of my dependencies via require. It also handles my routes
- `sdFunctions.js` has globals and other important things. But the most important is 2 global default views.

  - 1: The `GV` that everything goes through initially
  - 2: The `DV` that all options go through (The main navigation menu)

**Outline**

I know that for `OV` to load it must have the element that its loading into available. This is `el: 'sexdetails'`. This element gets loaded from the `DV`. So I realise that `DV` needs to be in the DOM for the `OV` to load. Otherwise it has no element to load into. [image]

This is a console load. `page` is from the `GV` `sexdetails` gets loaded in from the `DV` and this is where the `OV` gets loaded into. all these consoles are out put in loading order. So from the top to the bottom.

The bottom seems to be seen in the last console.log which is greyed out as the `element` has been built with all the correct information. But for whatever reason it not output onto the page.

**JS**

Now the exciting parts :p

**DV - This is the second defaultView, the one that handles the menu and where the click events are bound.**

```
SD.defaultSexView = function(){
    //set up homeview
    var sexView = SD.defaultView.extend({
        el: 'page',
        jstemplate: JST['app/www/js/templates/sex/sexTemplate.ejs'],
        events:{
            "click sexoptions > *" : 'changeSex'
        },
        changeSex: function(elem){

            var me = elem.currentTarget.localName;

            $('.selected').removeClass('selected');// #update selected from bottom navigation
            $(me).addClass('selected');

            SD.pageLoad(elem); // #Call function that will re-render the page
        },
        render: function () {
            var compiled = this.jstemplate();
            this.$el.html(compiled);
        }
    });
    SD.DSV = new sexView();
    SD.DSV.render();
    return sexView;
}();
```

**Own View - each of the 5 files has one of these**

```
//set up homeview
var wank = SD.defaultSexView.extend({
    el: 'sexdetails',
    jstemplate: JST['app/www/js/templates/sex.ejs'],
    data: {
        url: SD.HTTP+'stats/add',
        sextype: 'wank',
        header: 'SOME LOUD STRING!!!',
        image: '/img/path.jpg'
    },
    render: function () {
        c($('sexdetails'));
        c(this.$el);
        var compiled = this.jstemplate(this.data);
        this.$el.html(compiled);
    }
});
return wank;
```

All the code in full working order can be found here: http://m.sexdiaries.co.uk/ - don't be put off by the URL, I assure you its SFW. Everything is done with cartoons and in no crude.

**Interestingly if I update the code to use: `$('sexdetails').html(compiled);` it will indeed display correctly, but none of the events will be bound correctly.**

Sorry there is so much to take in, I'll be very very impressed if anybody takes the time out to read or understand this :)

Comment: I've spent quite a bit of time today trying to work out how, if possible, I could change my build or the approach to the problem. It is simple really, I want to on click, change a to a template, then once this template has loaded load in the new stuff. Why is it so difficult.

Comment: Also, could somebody please explain the downvote? If I'm doing something wrong I really really would love to know. Spent 5 days on this now.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't look into full code. But from my past experience I can say that you are rendering view on a element which might have been removed from page DOM. When you update this.$el.html() of a view, it will take away element from DOM but still maintain elements if referred in a closure. I can see that you are passing

```
SD.pageLoad(elem)
```

to some function which does rendering. Since elem is an object, it's passed by reference. even after you update view's template later with

```
var compiled = this.jstemplate();
this.$el.html(compiled);
```

element that is send to rendering function remains in memory, but not in DOM, so any element rendered on this element will not be displayed on page. Also you are using $ inside a view, but you should be using this.$. this will make sure that, code from a view will never change elements outside that view.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Well, interestingly with the code in its current state, the `DV` gets displayed on the click only the `OV` does not. But with your suggestion I'll see if I can't try and reinsert the whats still in the `DOM`

Comment: Just to add to this, if I update the code to use: `$('sexdetails').html(compiled);` it will indeed display correctly, but none of the events will be bound correctly. So I'll need to work this out. I need it to be in a function really as `SD.pageLoad` is being used in at least 7 separate files.

Answer (score 1):

After taking a look at your code, I noticed that in your "Wank" view, that you are setting `el` to `sexdetails`, which doesn't fly.  I wasn't able to dig into the details of why this is, but I assume it has something to do with lack of DOM specificity.

Setting `el` to "body content page" however, allowed to view to render without any issues, as this allowed to view to hook directly into the body of the page and lets the `render` function do the rest of the work for you.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm going to explore this now cheers :) Cheers very much for taking the time to look as well. Only problem with setting it to `body` will mean it will overwrite the templates called in the `DV`, which has the subnav inside of it.

Comment: Ah, good point!  Sorry I totally didn't notice that.  Instead, why not set `el` to "body content page" instead.  That should do the trick :) I've updated my original answer to reflect this.

Comment: arghh interesting :p i shall give this a whirl!

Comment: just thought, doesn't the target `el` overwrite whatever is in there? Meaning it'll overwrite the template `jst` :)

Comment: It was my understanding that `el` simply hooks into an existing element if it is available, but I could totally be wrong about that.  The docs aren't entirely clear on the matter either.  I can't do a jsfiddle just yet, but I'll give this a whirl later on and see if I can verify anything.

Comment: fingers crossed man :) I've spent tonight trying to solve this again lol

Comment: Any luck after last nights effort?  I mucked around with the code again on my end and modifying the `el` attribute as previously recommended seemed to do the trick without affecting event bindings in any bad ways.

Comment: Ye, i had to go with using a jQuery selector which is bad times. Even though all the events still work it seems like unessesery overhead :) might be I'm over thinking it mind you. \so what was your soultion? Just a few lines changes, I'll try them now :)